# Does wordpress clean up your action hooks?

Tags: wordpress

I've written a Wordpress plugin. I hook to some actions from another plugin and everything works, but I want to know, when I deactivate my plugin, do these actions still get called and executed, or does Wordpress remove them automatically?

I tried removing actions on deactivate hook, but something doesn't make much sense to me. I'm using OOP.
When adding an action, I add the callable with an array like this in a `registerActions` function:

```
add_action('gform_validation_' . $form_id, array($this, 'formValidate'));
```

and remove it in `unregisterActions` function:

```
remove_action('gform_validation_' . $form_id, array($this, 'formValidate'));
```

My problem:
The `registerActions` and `unregisterActions` functions are called to different instances of the same class. Is `remove_action` actually removing the same action I've created?
I couldn't find anything discussing this on the internet and it really left me wondering.

**Edit:** I guess I could store the instances and actually call the `registerActions` and `unregisterActions` functions on the same instance. But how do I do it properly? I could also make action functions static.

Comment: If your plugin is deactivated, it will not affect the actions from another plugin - since your code is no longer running. Actions are executed at run time, they are not persistent. This would be a huge problem if plugins could remove/add actions and it remained persistent.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding this correctly, I shouldn't worry about removing actions as they automatically "not work" when plugin is deactivated or removed? What about cron jobs? Do they also stop executing?

Comment: Correct, you don't need to remove any actions, since those are all runtime executions that depend on your code being available, which it won't be. Cron jobs will still execute, but they won't do anything since the cron call back will not be available. You should try and remove cron tasks on deactivation.